# How to stop multiple method callings on tap of first push notification (multiple push notifications coming)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, apple-push-notifications

When multiple messages are sent to a device, push notifications are received.

**Case 1:** Single message sent, single notification received and single calling of method handling the notification. Works fine.

**Case 2:** Multiple notifications received and multiple calling of method occurs on the tap of the first notification (on quick tap of first notification).

How do I prevent the method getting called multiple times when the notification is tapped?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(nonnull NSDictionary *)userInfo
{

    NSDictionary *dictToPass = userInfo[@"aps"];


   if([dictToPass[@"oId"] isEqualToString @"callMethod1"])
   {
       // call method 1
   }
   else if([dictToPass[@"oId"] isEqualToString @"callMethod2"])
   {
       // call method 2
   }    
}
```